# Plain DOM fadeOut then fadeIn immediately

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, fadein, fadeout

I would like to implement fadeIn and fadeOut using the native DOM, without JQuery.

If we click the button twice fast, means it will start to fadeOut when fadeIn is still ongoing, the text will be flickering.

Here's the codes in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/keegoo/vyuqdxLs/

Any ideas on how to fix that?

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => switch_state())
const text = document.getElementById('text')
const btn = document.getElementById('button')
let state = true

function switch_state() {
  if (state == true) {
    fadeOut(text, 3000)
    btn.innerHTML = 'show'
    state = false
  } else {
    fadeIn(text, 3000)
    state = true
    btn.innerHTML = 'hide'
  }
}

function fadeOut(elem, ms) {
  elem.style.opacity = 1
  if (ms) {
    let opacity = 1
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      opacity -= 50 / ms
      if (opacity <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        opacity = 0
      }
      elem.style.opacity = opacity
    }, 50)
  } else {
    elem.style.opacity = 0
  }
}

function fadeIn(elem, ms) {
  elem.style.opacity = 0;

  if (ms) {
    let opacity = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(function() {
      opacity += 50 / ms;
      if (opacity >= 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        opacity = 1;
      }
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
    }, 50);
  } else {
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>hide</button>
<text id='text'>some text</text>
```

Comment: `clearInterval(timer);` every time before you set it - and use `let timer`

Comment: Use CSS transitions instead of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, but I have to pass the `timer` to clearInterval(). Does it mean I have to define the timer globally ? Could you please be more specific. Very curious how to do that in plain JS

Comment: Yes, make the timer global and reuse it by clearing it every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this with `setProperty`.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => switch_state())
const text = document.getElementById('text')
const btn = document.getElementById('button')
let state = true

function switch_state() {
  if (state == true) {
    fadeOut(text, 800)
    btn.innerHTML = 'show'
    state = false
  } else {
    fadeIn(text, 800)
    state = true
    btn.innerHTML = 'hide'
  }
}

function fadeOut(elem, ms) {
  elem.style.setProperty("opacity",0);
  elem.style.setProperty("transition", "opacity " + ms + "ms");
}

function fadeIn(elem, ms) {
  elem.style.setProperty("opacity",1);
  elem.style.setProperty("transition", "opacity " + ms + "ms");
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>hide</button>
<text id='text'>some text</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd better define a `hidden` class style in a separate css file and set the transition time using that class. This will be much better for performance on the client, as well as stability and debugging.

The css should be something like this:

```
#text {
  transition: ease-in-out 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

#text.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then, You should only toggle changing the class in Js. What I've done in the following sample code is that I tried to double check the initial state of the text and button. So, I supposed that there's an initial `hidden` class on the text, which is wrong, so first before anything we need to set it correct. This is the reason for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to be there.

Then after setting the initial state, we don't know if the text element has any classes on it or not, so if it doesn't have any classes on it, it might give an error of undefined variable when we test aginst `text.classList` even it fulfills the condition and doesn't contain the `hidden` class. This is why in the `if` statement we should test if the `classList` is exisiting at all, then we will need to test whatever we want.

In the `else` I've wrpapped `text.classlist.add()` in a `try/catch` because of the same reason; if I've immediately used `text.classList.add()` it might fail when there's no classlist at all. In this case, we realize that if we have overwritten the `class` property of the element, we will not lose any previously set classes, they're not existing, so we catch that error and assign the class directly to the property.

This is how it would look like:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    switch_state()
})
const text = document.getElementById('text')
const btn = document.getElementById('button')

// First when we initialize the page, it should set the status of the text and button. Better for debugging.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (text.classList && text.classList.value.includes('hidden')) {
    text.classList.toggle('hidden')
    btn.innerHTML = 'Hide'
  }
})

// Then we run our manipulation.
function switch_state() {
  if (text.classList && text.classList.value.includes('hidden')) { // If there's a classList AND it contains 'hidden'
    text.classList.remove('hidden')
    btn.innerHTML = 'Hide'
  } else { // Reaching here makes us unsure if the reason is because there is no classList, or it's because the 'hidden' class is not in the classList
    try { // So first we assume there's a classList
      text.classList.add('hidden')
      btn.innerHTML = 'Show'
    } catch (error) { // Or we fail to the last probability of having no classList at all
      text.class = 'hidden'
      btn.innerHTML = 'Show'
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I've explained it well.

Comment: PS: There are some comments about your code, but I didn't fix them in the answer, to make you able to focus just on the solution.
For Example, The `switch_state` function is a better place to define the `text` and `btn` variables instead of defining them in the open space :). That makes them volnerable to be overwritten by any other js on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS custom properties:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", switch_state)
const text = document.getElementById('text')
const btn = document.getElementById('button')
let state = true
let root = document.documentElement;

function switch_state() {
  if (state == true) {
    fadeOut(text, 3000)
    btn.innerHTML = 'show'
    state = false
  } else {
    fadeIn(text, 3000)
    state = true
    btn.innerHTML = 'hide'
  }
}

// Native fadeOut
function fadeOut(elem, ms) {
  root.style.setProperty('--opacity', 0);
  root.style.setProperty('--transition', "1s");
}

// Native fadeIn
function fadeIn(elem, ms) {
  root.style.setProperty('--opacity', 1);
  root.style.setProperty('--transition', "1s");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --transition: 1s;
  --opacity: 1;
}

#text {
  opacity: var(--opacity);
  transition: all var(--transition);
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>hide</button>
<text id='text'>some text</text>
```

Comment: @mplungjan that's because I set fadeout transition to 5s. It is working fine now.